# A possible way to determine a set may or may not basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

It is known that $v = [1, x, x^2, \cdots]$ is the basis for polynomials. Taking $P_2$ as an example, if I have a set $w = [1, x, 2x^2-1]$, one way to show this set is basis is shown in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215089/how-to-prove-that-1-x-x2-is-a-basis-of-a-real-polynomial-functions-space), which is quite straightforward. I am wondering if this set could be written as an linear transformation, i.e, $w=vA$ and $A$ is invertible, then I could also conclude that $w$ is a basis?

There is a problem seems to be relevant:

Suppose that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is a linearly independent set in $C^m$. Prove that:
$$\{v_1,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_2+v_3,v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4\}$$
is also a linearly independent set.

**My Conclusion**

With the generous help from @egreg and @Attack68, I understand that this is an alternative when determining whether or not a given set is a basis for vector space.

If the set to be tested $w$ could be written in the form $w = vA$ (where $v$ is original basis and $A$ is transition matrix used to make possible the change of basis) and $A$ is full rank.

According to following fact about rank of matrix $A, B$(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) for more information),

$$rank(A)+rank(B)-n\leq rank(AB) \leq \mathrm{min}\{rank(A)+rank(B)\}$$

where $A\subseteq R^{m\times n}$ and $B\subseteq R^{n\times k}$

When $v = [1, x, x^2]$ and $w = [1, x, 2x^2-1]$, we have $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&-1\\0&1&0\\0&0&2 \end{pmatrix}$, whose rank is obviously 3. Therefore, according to the inequalities we have $3 \leq rank(w)\leq 3$.

Now we could say that $w$ is the new basis for vector space.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the subspace $V$ spanned by $B=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$; this is a basis and the other four vectors you have live in $V$. Thus they are linearly independent if and only if their coordinate vectors with respect to $B$ (which is a basis of $V$) are linearly independent, that is, if and only if the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
has rank $4$, which it has.

Alternatively, observe that
\begin{align}
v_1&=v_1\\
v_2&=(v_1+v_2)-v_1 \\
v_3&=(v_1+v_2+v_3)-(v_1+v_2) \\
v_4&=(v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4)-(v_1+v_2+v_3)
\end{align}
so the second set is also a spanning set for $V$. Since $\dim V=4$, this set is a basis.

Comment: But the fact that upper triangular matrix, which I call $A$, is full rank seems to only tell us that four columns in $A$ are linearly independent but could not tell us the "new basis" is linearly independent.

Comment: @Mr.Robot Why not? It *does* tell you that.

Comment: I understand now, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Any vector $v$ in your space can be written as a linear combination of the original vectors $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$ since they span the space.
$$ v = \sum_1^4 k_i v_i$$
Considering a second basis $\{w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4\}=\{v_1, v_1+v_2, v_1+v_2+v_3, v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4\}$ then you can write the same vector $v$ as:
$$v=\sum_1^4 K_iw_i $$
where $K_4=k_4$, $K_3=k_3-K_4$, $K_2=k_2-K_3-K_4$, $K_1=k_1-K_2-K_3-K_4$.
Therefore $v$ can be written as linear combination of $w_i$ hence it forms a basis.